Story about the Ben Ish Chai selling his precious sefer Torah in order to publish his seforim
Rav Daniel Glatstein in his Maggid HaRakiah (Inyanei Purim) quotes a story about the Ben Ish Chai desperately wanting to sell his seforim but had no money to publish them. The story goes that he had in possession a really rare Sefer Torah, a few hundred years old, that he wanted to sell as a מנחה אל הבארון רוטשילד (Baron Rothschild) of Paris. In exchange for the Sefer Torah, he hoped that he could print his essays and distribute them in Israel for free.
Seemingly, Rabbi Yaakov Hillel, in his biography on the Ben Ish Chai has a rare letter in this book that describe this as follows:

The Ben Ish Chai was supported by his brothers, who had a business in India. The business went sour, and money was lost, and his brothers
were also imprisoned. Besides the fact that he had no money for food,
he had no money for publishing his seforim. He had a really small
sefer Torah, where the paper was as thin as an onion peel. The Ben Ish
Chai wrote to a really wealthy woman, asked her to intercede on his
behalf, so that Rothschild buys the sefer Torah, so that the Ben Ish
Chai would have money to sell his seforim.

Does anyone know where this letter can be found in this book from Rabbi Hillel and what exactly it says?
Unfortunately, I did not find any locations to buy the biography that ship to my country, otherwise I would have checked it myself :)

Isn’t that against Halacha according to the Mishnah in megilla about אין מורידין בקדושה

@CuriousYid I don't know. I don't have the original sources though. I remember reading that he justified it, but I can be wrong.

He probably sold it to the sassoon family or some other high roller on condition they restore it to synagogue use. He may have structured it as a gift, not a sale, to avoid halachic complications. Shukchan aruch and other sources have more exceptions.  https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/

You could call the publisher of his Anthology and ask if it includes the original title pages, which may reference the original sponsorship.  https://seforimcenter.com/Ben-Ish-Hai-Anthology---11-volume-set__p-4844.aspx

As promised awhile back, the letter from Rabbi Hillel's book (the Hebrew edition), pp. 122-124:

"...אחרי עתרת החיים והשלום את קסת'י נתתי להודיע להדרת גאונו וכו', כי נמצא איתי ספר תורה שלם קטן הכמות ורב האיכות, נכתב בזמן קדמון בתחילת מאה השישית ביד חכם חסיד בקדושה ובטהרה, כתיבה דקה מעין כתיבת ספר תורה הקשור בזרועו של מלך, על קלף כשר דק מאד כקלפי בצלים שעשאו בידו ממש ביגיעה רבה, תמשך זמן כתיבתו בידו קרוב לחמש שנים. ולסוף ספר תורה זה נעשה חלקי וחביב עלי מאד, ואע"פ שלא נקרא בו עדיין בציבור מחמת קוטן מדתו, הנה הנחתו בבית היא ברכה וגם הוא נכון להקיף בו בחג שמחת התורה.
ומודע לבינ'ה דאנא עבדא הייתי עשיר, שהייתי שותף עם אחי העוסקים בסחורות ומשא ומתן רב, אך בעוה"ר הזמן בוגד ונשארתי נקי, וקשה עלי לבקש סמך ועזר מאחרים המכירים אותי מפני כי הייתי אני מן העוזרים והמחזיקים ביד אחרים, ודי בזה לחכם שכמותו. והנה בעתה רב צערי ביותר על אשר אין לאל ידי להדפיס חיבורי היקרים, והדפסתי מקדמא דנא מעט מזעיר מהם, ויש לי תשוקה גדולה להדפיס חיבורי מטעם הידוע להדרת גאונו, וקשה עלי צער זה יותר מצער דוחק הפרנסה.
על כן עלה בלבי לשלוח ספר תורה היקר הנז"ל בתורת מנחה אל הבארון רוטשילד הי"ו בפאריז, באמצעות הגבירה סי' רחל מב"ת בתו של השר הגדול אלבארת ששון נ"ע, כי היה לי ידיעה עם בעלה, וחשבתי בדעתי מה שישלח לי תמורת הספר תורה ולא נחשב לי כמוכר ספר תורה, וכן עשיתי ושלחתי הספר תורה הנז' לידה, אך לא הסתייעא מלתא שתמסרנו ליד הבארון הנז', כי אמרה משיקול דעתה שהבארון הנז' אין לו תשוקה בעניינים אלו, על כן חשבה שמחשבתי לא תצא לפועל כאשר שיערתי בדעתי, ובו בפרק כתבתי לה שישאר הספר תורה שמור אצלה עד אשר אראה אופן מה לעשות בו.
והן היום עלה בדעתי להפיק מחשבתי הנז' לשלוח הספר תורה הנז' בתורת מנחה להגבירה בארונא די הרש ויהיה ברכה בביתה, ושיערתי בדעתי שמנחתי הזאת תעשה פרי כאשר חשבתי אם תהיה הגשת המנחה על ידי הדרת גאונו, כי בדבריו הטובים ושיחתו הנעימה היוצאים מלב טוב וישר ודאי יצא פרי טוב כאשר כלבבי, וגדול המעשה וכו', על כן בזה היום כתבתי להגברת סי' רחל הנז' שתשלח הספר תורה הנז' להדרת גאונו, ומעלת כבודו יקיים בו מצות שילוח בתורת מנחה להגברת בעלת צדקה וחסד בארונה די הרש משמי, ולא כתבתי מכתב לשמה הטוב כי אמרתי אמרותיו היקרים היוצאים מלב טהור המלא חסד ורחמים הם טובים מן דברי המכתב שלי..."

Picture of part of the letter:

To summarize: The letter was written to Rabbi Tzaddok Kahn, rabbi of Paris by the Ben Ish Chai. The Ben Ish Chai had fallen into some monetary difficulties but wanted to publish his books, so he thought of sending an ancient Torah scroll he had to Baron Rothschild in hopes of the Baron giving him some money in return. The method of the "transaction" was supposed to be done in a manner that would not be considered directly selling the scroll, since technically he was gifting the scroll to the Baron and was not conditioning the gift on reception of payment. The Ben Ish Chai had originally requested that Rachel, the daughter of Albert Sassoon, intercede on his behalf, but after receiving the scroll she informed the Ben Ish Chai that it would be a waste of time. The Ben Ish Chai then decided to ask Rabbi Kahn to deliver the scroll to the Baroness de Hirsch instead.

Wonderful. Many thanks! Curious Yid commented with the question whether it was allowed or not to sell the sefer Torah. "The method of the "transaction" was supposed to be done in a manner that would not be considered directly selling the scroll, since technically he was gifting the scroll to the Baron and was not conditioning the gift on reception of payment." - is this allowed as per halacha?

@Shmuel presumably the Ben Ish Chai thought it worked because he himself explained that that was why he was doing it that way. But I don't have sources on the matter.

Thanks, really appreciate it. Gut Shabbos!

Happy to help. Shabbat Shalom!

B"H I found this story in the sefer Hareah Hatov Ben Ish Chai (p. 101-102) by Rabbi Avishay Barosher. It writes:

אותי, מפני כי הייתי אני מן העוזרים והמחזיקים ביד אחרים, ודי בזה לחכם
שכמותו. והנה עתה רב צערי ביותר על אשר אין לאל ידי להדפיס חיבורי
היקרים, והדפסתי מקדמת דנא מעט מזעיר מהם, ויש לי תשוקה גדולה להדפיס
חיבורי, מטעם הידוע להדרת גאונו, וקשה עלי צער זה יותר מצער דוחק הפרנסה.
על כן עלה בלבי לשלוח ספר תורה היקר הנז"ל בתורת מנחה אל הבארון רוטשילד
הי"ו בפאריז, באמצעות הגבירה סיניור רחל מב"ת, בתו של השר הגדול אלבארת
ששון נ"ע, כי היה לי ידיעה עם בעלה, וחשבתי בדעתי מה שישלח לי תמורת הספר
תורה הנזכר, אדפיס חיבורים שלי ואחלקם בישראל בחינם, ונמצא אין אני נהנה
לעצמן מן הספר תורה ולא נחשב לי כמוכר ספר תורה. וכן עשיתי ושלחתי הס"ת
הנזכר לידה, אך לא אסתייעא מילתא שתמסרנו ליד הבארון הנזכר, כי אמרה
משיקול דעתה, שהבארון הנזכר אין לו תשוקה בעניינים אלו, על כן חשבה
שמחשבתי לא תצא לפועל כאשר שיערתי בדעתי. ובו בפרק כתבתי לה שישאר הספר
תרה שמור אצלה עד אשר אראה אופן מה לעשות בו.
[...] And now my sorrow is very
great because I do not have the means to print my precious writings,
and I have previously printed a very small amount of them, and I have
a great desire to print my compositions, and this sorrow is harder for me than the sorrow
of financial strain.
Therefore, it occurred to me to send the precious Torah scroll
to Baron Rothschild, may he live, in
Paris, through the distinguished Mrs. Rachel Mivashat, the daughter of
the great minister Albert Sassoon, may he rest in peace, since I had
acquaintance with her husband, and I thought in my mind what he would
send me in exchange for the mentioned Torah scroll, I would print my
compositions and distribute them in Israel for free, and it would be
found that I do not benefit myself from the Torah scroll and it is not
considered as if I am selling a Torah scroll. And so I did and sent
the mentioned Torah scroll to her, but the matter was not helped that
it would be delivered to the mentioned baron, for she said from her
own judgment that the mentioned baron has no desire for these matters,
therefore she thought that my plan would not materialize as I had
imagined in my mind. And in that chapter I wrote to her that the Torah
scroll should remain with her until I see a way what to do with it.

